# upload to amazon S3

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload pictures to amazon S3. I was successful using carrierwave. Then I switched to jQuery multi image upload. Following railscast 383.

my upload_helper looks exactly as shown; except the initialize method. 
https://github.com/railscasts/383-uploading-to-amazon-s3/blob/master/gallery-jquery-fileupload/app/helpers/upload_helper.rb

following is in the page that user can upload their pics:

```
    = s3_uploader_form post: items_url, as: "painting[image_url]" do
        = file_field_tag :file, multiple: true

    %script#template-upload{type: "text/x-tmpl"}
        .upload
            {%=o.name%}
            .progress
                .bar{ style: "width: 0%" }
```

I have the following js too:

```
//= require jquery-fileupload/basic
//= require jquery-fileupload/vendor/tmpl
//= require paintings
```

as it was shown in the tutorial

Even though my S3 upload was working fine with carrierwave and single file upload I am getting

```
failed to upload image error (coming from the last line in paintings.js.coffee). and 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)

<Error>
    <Code>AccessDenied</Code>
    <Message>Access Denied</Message>
    <RequestId>XYZ</RequestId>
    <HostId>
        XYZ
    </HostId>
</Error>
```

my CORS configuration is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration>
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>http://localhost:3000</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
        <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
        <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Any guidance is very much appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found it!!!

In the upload_helper > S3Uploader > initialze add a timezone to your 'expiration:' like this:

```
    expiration: 10.hours.from_now.utc,
```

That did the magic for me

Good luck